# sudo apt-get update failes because It can't be done securely

Tags: apt

I want to run `sudo apt-get update` in order to be able to install some packages needed for ns3

for example when I run `sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev`

It gives this error: `Unable to locate package ibgtk-3-dev` .

and as I searched I should run `sudo apt-get update`  but It's not updating and this is output:

[image]

How can I solve this problem? Thank in advance.

Comment: Which ubuntu version do you use?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: It's not a error. It's the expected behavior for a release of Ubuntu that reached End Of Life over two years ago. Those repositories have been withdrawn.

Comment: Thanks.It seems I should update my ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ArtfulAardvark/ReleaseNotes

17.10 is not supported anymore - you should upgrade to a newer version

I'd recommend using a LTS version, those are supported for 3 to 5 years

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: I there a  command to update to latest version ?

Comment: I believe 17.10 can be upgraded to 18.04 (a LTS) which can be upgraded to 20.04 (also LTS) - to go directly to 20.10 or 20.04 you would have to reinstalkl and reconfigure your computer - https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-17-10-end-of-life/ - in any case a good backup might be a good idea before doing a distribution-upgrade or reinstall to newer version. to avoid needing to do an upgrade regularly choosing a LTS version would be a good idea - i.e>. 20.04 at this moment

Comment: Thank for your help.